# How to manually add offline dependency to Rust Project without using cargo vendor

Tags: rust, rust-cargo

I am currently looking into integrating Rust into my workflow and am running into a bit of an issue right now. This is my situation:

1. I have 2 systems, system A and system B
2. B has no connection to the internet but I can access B through A and copy-pasta things from A to B
3. B is the environment for Rust and will be used for running Rust and Cargo
4. A has access to the internet but cannot run any Cargo/Rust commands

As an example, let’s say I am making a project where I depend on the rand 0.8.5 crate for my project. Ideally I would use the cargo vendor command to offline the dependency but because of points 2) and 4) I cannot do that. Moreover, this is what I think I need to do but cannot figure out how to do it:

A) download the rand repository from GitHub on A

B) manually make a .cargo/config.toml and vendor/ on B

C) copy pasta rand download from A to vendor in B BUT…

Because the rand repository on GitHub doesn’t match with the folder hierarchy when off-lining rand using cargo vendor, I get errors when I do a copy of the rand download to vendor. Moreover, I was hoping if anyone knows how to easily get the rand repository to work (no, “ just match the file hierarchy” isn’t the answer I am looking for as I would not know what the hierarchy should be like due to not being able to successfully run cargo vendor) or know if I am not doing something correctly. I understand my situation is particularly unusual so please feel free to ask for any clarification. Thanks!

Comment: Can you download it on A then move it to B via flash drive or something? Then you can just reference the local project in `Cargo.toml`. If you don't have physical access then you should be able to `scp` the directory over LAN.

Comment: I think the confusion was over how to integrate the GitHub download of a library/crate to an offline rust project since it didn’t match the layout expected in vendor. However, I did figure it out and made an answer to my own question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I figured it out!

First I download rand off of GitHub and move it from A to B and then in Cargo.toml I do the following:

[dependencies]
rand = { path = “path/to/rand/GitHub/download” }

This actually will still not work and will cause issues and turns out dependencies have dependencies and thankfully the compiler tells you what is needed so it’s the same process with those other ones except adjustments are needed to be done to the Cargo.toml for the dependency (rand in this example). Finally use cargo run —offline and boom sauce, it works

Answer (score 1):

You can use cargo fetch and prefetch

For downloading crates for offline use..

```
// Install cargo prefetch

$ cargo install cargo-prefetch
```

[Cargo fetch](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/commands/cargo-fetch.html)

[Cargo prefetch](https://crates.io/crates/cargo-prefetch)

Then Try moving the files from A to B

Take a look at these files for configuration:

```
.crates.toml
.crates2.json
```

Comment: This seems to be good for a system that goes offline, however in my case the offline system is always offline. I cannot run any cargo commands on the online system. I did eventually figure it out (made an answer to my own question)